# Creating a chat library in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am an experienced Java programmer, but fairly new to JavaScript.

I am creating a chat library in JavaScript, and have it working, but want to know if I am going about this correctly, and following correct JavaScript coding standards.

I have a `SDK` object, `LiveChatConnection` class, and `LiveChatListener` and `Credentials` interfaces (I know classes and interfaces do not exist in JavaScript, but this seems to be how to create them).

To declare methods I am using

```
this.myMethod = function() {...};
```

I have seen other libraries put methods on the class prototype

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {...}
```

or declare them like,

```
myMethod : function() {...}
```

Not sure which is best.

So my `SDK` will be packaged in a sdk.js file on my website, then users should be able to import and use it in their web pages.

Not sure if my code makes sense from a usage perspective, or if I'm missing anything else.

```
var SDK = {};

function Credentials() {
    this.host = "";
    this.app = "";
    this.url = "";
    this.applicationId = "";
}


/**
 * Listener interface for a LiveChatConnection.
 * This gives asynchronous notification when a channel receives a message, or notice.
 */
function LiveChatListener() {
    /**
     * A user message was received from the channel.
     */
    this.message = function(message) {};

    /**
     * An informational message was received from the channel.
     * Such as a new user joined, private request, etc.
     */ 
    this.info = function(message) {};

    /**
     * An error message was received from the channel.
     * This could be an access error, or message failure.
     */ 
    this.error = function(message) {};

    /**
     * Notification that the connection was closed.
     */
    this.closed = function() {};

    /**
     * The channels users changed (user joined, left, etc.)
     * This contains a comma separated values (CSV) list of the current channel users.
     * It can be passed to the SDKConnection.getUsers() API to obtain the UserConfig info for the users.
     */
    this.updateUsers = function(usersCSV) {};

    /**
     * The channels users changed (user joined, left, etc.)
     * This contains a HTML list of the current channel users.
     * It can be inserted into an HTML document to display the users.
     */
    this.updateUsersXML = function(usersXML) {};
}

/**
 * Connection class for a Live Chat, or chatroom connection.
 * A live chat connection is different than an SDKConnection as it is asynchronous,
 * and uses web sockets for communication.
 */
function LiveChatConnection(credentials) {
    this.debug = false;
    this.channel = null;
    this.user = null;
    this.credentials = credentials;
    this.socket = null;
    this.listener = null;
    this.keepAlive = false;
    this.keepAliveInterval = null;

    /**
     * Connection to the live chat server channel.
     * Validate the user credentials.
     * This call is asynchronous, any error or success with be sent as a separate message to the listener.
     */
    this.connect = function(channel, user) {
        if (this.credentials == null) {
            throw "Mising credentials";
        }
        this.channel = channel;
        this.user = user;
        var host = "ws://" + this.credentials.host + this.credentials.app + "/live/chat";
        if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            this.socket = new WebSocket(host);
        } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
            this.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
        } else {
            this.socket = new WebSocket(host);
            //throw 'Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.';
        }

        this.listener.connection = this;
        var self = this;

        this.socket.onopen = function () {
            if (self.user == null) {
                self.socket.send("connect " + self.channel.id + " " + self.credentials.applicationId);
            } else {
                self.socket.send(
                        "connect " + self.channel.id + " " + self.user.user + " " + self.user.token + " " + self.credentials.applicationId);                        
            }
            self.setKeepAlive(this.keepAlive);
        };

        this.socket.onclose = function () {
            self.listener.message("Info: Closed");
            self.listener.closed();
        };

        this.socket.onmessage = function (message) {
            user = "";
            data = message.data;
            text = data;
            index = text.indexOf(':');
            if (index != -1) {
                user = text.substring(0, index);
                data = text.substring(index + 2, text.length);
            }
            if (user == "Online-xml") {
                self.listener.updateUsersXML(data);
                return;
            }
            if (user == "Online") {
                self.listener.updateUsers(data);
                return;
            }

            if (self.keepAlive && user == "Info" && text.contains("pong")) {
                return;
            }
            if (user == "Info") {
                self.listener.info(text);
                return;
            }
            if (user == "Error") {
                self.listener.error(text);
                return;
            }
            self.listener.message(text);
        };
    };

    /**
     * Sent a text message to the channel.
     * This call is asynchronous, any error or success with be sent as a separate message to the listener.
     * Note, the listener will receive its own messages.
     */
    this.sendMessage = function(message) {
        this.checkSocket();
        this.socket.send(message);
    };

    /**
     * Accept a private request.
     * This is also used by an operator to accept the top of the waiting queue.
     * This can also be used by a user to chat with the channel bot.
     * This call is asynchronous, any error or success with be sent as a separate message to the listener.
     */
    this.accept = function() {
        this.checkSocket();
        this.socket.send("accept");
    };

    /**
     * Test the connection.
     * A pong message will be returned, this message will not be broadcast to the channel.
     * This call is asynchronous, any error or success with be sent as a separate message to the listener.
     */
    this.ping = function() {
        this.checkSocket();
        this.socket.send("ping");
    };

    /**
     * Exit from the current private channel.
     * This call is asynchronous, any error or success with be sent as a separate message to the listener.
     */
    this.exit = function() {
        this.checkSocket();
        this.socket.send("exit");
    };

    /**
     * Request a private chat session with a user.
     * This call is asynchronous, any error or success with be sent as a separate message to the listener.
     */
    this.pvt = function(user) {
        this.checkSocket();
        this.socket.send("pvt: " + user);
    };

    /**
     * Disconnect from the channel.
     */
    this.disconnect = function() {
        this.setKeepAlive(false);
        if (this.socket != null) {
            this.socket.disconnect();
        }
    };

    this.checkSocket = function() {
        if (this.socket == null) {
            throw "Not connected";
        }
    };

    this.toggleKeepAlive = function() {
        setKeepAlive(!this.keepAlive);
    }

    this.setKeepAlive = function(keepAlive) {
        this.keepAlive = keepAlive;
        if (!keepAlive && this.keepAliveInterval != null) {
            clearInterval(this.keepAliveInterval);
        } else if (keepAlive && this.keepAliveInterval == null) {
            this.keepAliveInterval = setInterval(
                    function() {
                        this.ping()
                    },
                    600000);
        }
    }
}

SDK.chime = function() {
    var sound = new Audio('chime.wav');
    sound.play();
}

SDK.url = "/botlibre/rest/botlibre";
SDK.tts = function(text) {
    try {
        var url = SDK.url + '/form-speak?&text=';
        url = url + encodeURIComponent(text);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState != 4) return;
            if (request.status != 200) {
                console.log('Error: Speech web request failed');
                return;
            }
            var audio = new Audio(request.responseText);
            audio.mediaGroup = 'voice';
            audio.play();
        }

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error: Speech web request failed');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at IIFEs: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Don't use `SDK` as a namespace. I have no idea what `SDK` we are talking about. Name the variable after the module and its purpose.

Comment: For your questions, see [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572) and [Defining a Javascript prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17474390/1048572). For feedback about your code, you should ask at [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 1):

For adding methods, the preferred form is `MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {...};`

Imagine if you created a thousand instances of `MyClass`, you would be defining `myMethod` a thousand times as well, which is not necessary. By putting the method on the prototype, it is only defined once, though every instance of `MyClass` can still access it.

Also, it's good to be mindful of which methods need to be public, and which can be private. For example:

```
var MyClass = (function(){

    var myClass = function(){};
    var privateMethod = function(){ return 1; };
    myClass.prototype.publicMethod = function(){ return (privateMethod() + 1); };

    return myClass;
})();
```

In the above example, `privateMethod` is defined locally, so that it doesn't clutter the global namespace, and also doesn't clutter the object properties of a `MyClass` instance, yet it is still available to be used by `publicMethod`.

This pattern uses an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) for defining the class, which is common in javascript library development.